# Need to implement Custom Layout Alert Dialog on listView item click

Tags: android, listview

I need suggestions.

I have a listview with items. I need to implement onitemclick in such a way that it ask for entering a value and value is also shown in that item(which i have clicked). Each row in listview contains a TextView and value should be updated upon clicking corresponding rows.

I am using listview in a fragment class.

I dont get any ideas. I need suggestions or ideas.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "pressed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

***how to get value from the custom dialog box which has an EditText 'Size' and 'OK' button. This value should be updated to the list.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom dialog in xml and show dialog in onitemclick for entering a value.

Try [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659766/Android-Custom-DialogBox)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to DialogFragment and a simple, custom listener.

1. For custom dialog, use `diaglogFragment.show();` from your `onListItemClick`.
2. To return values/update your listView, add a listener in your `DialogFragment` which is implemented by its calling Fragment.

Comment: can u provide some more brief on 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public class DialogAlert extends Dialog {
    Context mContext;
    Listeners mListeners;
    String mTitle;
    String mMessage;

    public DialogAlert (Context mContext, Listeners mListeners, String mTitle,
            String mMessage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(mContext);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListeners = mListeners;
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
        this.mMessage = mMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_alert);
        setCancelable(false);
        Typeface mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),
                "fonts/helvetica.otf");
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.confirm_title);
        TextView mMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.confirm_message);
        mTitle.setText(this.mTitle);
        mMessage.setText(this.mMessage);
        mTitle.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        mMessage.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        Button confirmOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm_ok);
        confirmOK.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mListeners.OnClickOk();
            }
        });
        Button dialogClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm_close);
        dialogClose.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View paramView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mListeners.OnClickClose();
            }
        });
        Button dialogCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm_cancel);
        dialogCancel
                .setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View paramView) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mListeners.OnClickCancel();
                    }
                });
        confirmOK.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        dialogCancel.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }

    public interface Listeners {
        void OnClickClose();

        void OnClickCancel();

        void OnClickOk();
    }
```

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/close_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dialog_left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm_close"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/dialog_close" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/confirm_title"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/close_container" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/close_container"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dialog_alert" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/confirm_message"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/close_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm_ok"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_alert"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm_cancel"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_alert"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/confirm_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/close_container"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_container"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="Are You Sure ?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/confirm_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/confirm_title"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Are you Sure you want to exit dude?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Dialogfragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) class

It provides dialogs with custom layots like activity

here is examplpe how to use it

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView messageText;

    private Button okButton;

    private String title;
    private String message;

    public Dialog(String title,String message) {
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container);

        messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_message);
        okButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);

        getDialog().setTitle(title);

        messageText.setText(message);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Layout for dialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_ok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can show your dialog using this code

```
Dialog d = new Dialog();
d.show(getSupportFragmetManager(), "Tag");
```

P.S if your app need to support earlier android versions like 2.2 you need to add appcompat library or sherlock library to your project